# Split Json file at certain size and continue in loop

Tags: python, json, csv, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to write a small script in python that gets a the follower IDs from a specific Twitter User, and saves them in a list in a JSON file. I'll later take that JSON file and run a Bot Scorer to determine which of the users from that follower are bots.

The issue I'm facing at the moment, is that the files get quite large, and I have limited RAM. I'd like to split the file at a certain size, and then continue in a new file. I've managed to stop the file at a certain size when I write to CSV with f.tell() like this:

```
api = tweepy.API(#authkeys)
source_id = (#twitterID)
user = api.get_user(source_id)
ids_list = list()

print("User ID:", user.id)
print("Follower Count:", user.followers_count)

with open('out.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  csvfile = csv.writer(f)
  maxsize = 1024               # max file size in bytes
  for friend in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, user_id=source_id).items():
    print(friend)
    ids_list.append(friend)
    csvfile.writerows(map(lambda x: [x], ids_list))
    if f.tell() > maxsize:    
        break
```

However, with this I'm getting duplicate IDs. I think what's happening is that it keeps adding the list from the start, instead of making one list and adding to that. I understand that it writes rows in CSV, but in JSON it's supposed to format a list, that I'll be able to read later. I've managed to remove duplicates by casting the list to a set when I write it to JSON, but then I don't know how to f.tell the size of the JSON to stop it at a certain size. Also, If I do get f.tell() or a similar method to work, I don't know how to let it continue with a new file, say "out2" dot json or txt, where it left off. At this point, I've only managed to break the loop.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you write the bot scorer?

Comment: @Tomalak I only wrote the script that uses botometer ( https://botometer.iuni.iu.edu/#!/) and categorises them using that result.

Comment: So you wrote the part that reads the JSON file? Maybe it's best to switch strategies. JSON might not be the best format for this. You might want to try using CSV - this can be of any size, it can be read line-wise very efficiently (i.e. it can be streamed). There are also libraries that can stream JSON (like http://pykler.github.io/yajl-py/ or https://github.com/kashifrazzaqui/json-streamer), but think about whether there is a good reason to keep using JSON for this.

Comment: Another option would be to use a database (like sqlite) instead.

Comment: You're right, I'm not particularly locked in for JSON, I can change the reader easily. I've already spent more time on the CSV solution, as I'm making the most progress there. Thanks @Tomalak!